# Why does an EXCEPT statment complete faster than its two select statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, except

I was running an EXCEPT statement on a pair of select statements that, when run individually, would take 3-4 seconds, apiece, to run to completion. (I'm testing my code on big data sets)

Now When linked by an except statement, the whole query completes in under a second. Not that I'm complaining, but I'm now very curious how this is possible?  Is it a caching thing since I ran the two select queries prior to the EXCEPT query, or can I expect performance like this when it is run as an automated process?

Response to comments:
I cannot give the exact sql or datatables for security reasons but the basics are thus

`Select * From Exampletable
EXCEPT
Select * from Identicalexampletable`

The each select statement, when run individually, takes 3-4 seconds apiece. The total number of records returned between them is roughly 430k

Comment: you have to paste queries,schema of tables involved and count of tables for us to help you

Comment: Both tables take 3-4 seconds or combined they take 3-4 seconds?

Comment: I suspect caching, have you tried running your separate queries again? If those are faster than the first time, caching is most likely the explanation. You should also look at the execution plan to see what the server is doing. Perhaps the EXCEPT starts using an index or eliminates a table scan...

Comment: Not entirely sure how to interpret the EXEC. PLAN, but the part where i suspect the except statement is taking place is begin done with a Hash Match (left anti semi join) Cost 27%. Not sure if that's meaningful to anyone.